# Поиск значений в json на c#

Tags: c#, json

Мне нужно получать json из веб-сервиса, потом пройтись по нему, чтобы найти определённые значения. Основной проблемой является то, что json приходит в виде

[{данные},{данные}, ...] то есть нету корневого элемента. Раньше брал из файла и просто добавил заголовок, что позволило перебирать. Сейчас это очень неудобно было бы делать, подскажите, есть ли возможность нормально работать с json такого формата и если да, то как?

Comment: пробовали парсить как массив?

Comment: Я, кажется, увидел в вопросе скрытый смысл... А не может быть так, что у автора json - это просто представление для потока данных? То есть, этакий json'чик с началом, но без конца: в него всё время выплёвываются порции данных, и парсить его надо, не дожидаясь скачивания (потому, что можно никогда не дождаться). Есть ли средства работы с такими Json-чиками?

Comment: я погуглил. Предположу, что речь идёт о потоковой перодаче json'а

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming
И есть такой прекрасный ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747477/how-to-parse-huge-json-file-as-stream-in-json-net

Comment: `var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyDataClass>>(json);`, дальше работаете с items как со списком ваших данных

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте NuGet Newtonsoft.Json и попробуйте перебрать так:

```
string json = "[{\"key\":\"value1\"},{\"key\":\"value2\"},{\"key\":\"value3\"}]";
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach (var e in array) {
    Console.WriteLine(e["key"]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообщем, предположу, что есть некий запрос к веб-сервису:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your_address");
//параметры запроса
```

Далее, нам нужно получить результат (ответ) от самого вэб-сервиса:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Теперь, при условии, что мы получили некий response, его нужно как-то прочитать, и десериализовать, пример:

```
//json формата [{data_obj1},{data_obj2},...{data_objN}] мы можем десериализовать в список, не используя root_object 
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<data_object>));
List<data_object> recieved_data = new List<data_object>();
using(var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true))
{
   recieved_data = ser.ReadObject(reader) as List<data_object>
}
```

Так как в примере используются объекты из пространства имен System.Runtime.Serialization и System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, соответственно следует описать и объект data_object:

```
[DataContract]
public class data_object
{
  [DataMember]
  public string prop1 {get;set;}
  [DataMember]
  public string prop2 {get;set;}
  ...
  [DataMember]
  public string propN {get;set;}
}
```

Ну а поиск реализовать средствами Linq или перебором:
LINQ:

```
var f_data_object = recieved_data.Where(it => it.prop1 == "Foo").FirstOrDefault();;
```

Перебор:

```
foreach(var item in received_data)
{
  if(item.prop1 == "Foo")
  {
    //TA-DAM!!!
  }
}
```